# как добавить html в view django

Tags: python, html, django, view

У меня есть Viev который собирает данные с формы и отправляет на email, мне нужно что бы на email приходили данные с новой строчки, я пробовал добавить в переменную message теги списка но на почту эти тэги приходят просто текстом и все в 1 строчку

помогите пожалуйста!!!

Мой View

```
def message_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedBackLite(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = \
                      'Имя: ' + form.cleaned_data['name'] + \
                      ' Телефон: ' + form.cleaned_data['phone'] + \
                      ' Е-mail ' + form.cleaned_data['email'] + \
                      ' Конец сообщения'
            mail = send_mail(form.cleaned_data['name'], message, 'dev@test.tech',
                             ['test@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
            if mail:
                print('success_message')
                form.save()
                return redirect(forms_success)
            else:
                print('error_message')
    else:
        form = FeedBackLite()
```

На почту это приходит вот так в одну строчку    `Имя: Имя имя имя Телефон: +7 (999) 999-9999Е-mail test@gmail.com Конец сообщения`

а нужно что бы с новой строки

Comment: Ну вы все в одну строку склеиваете через пробел, поэтому все в одну строку и получается. Если у вас там html в итоге формируется, то добавляйте перенос через `<br />`, например (или как вариант маркированный список делайте через `<ul>`).

Comment: Это не сработает Все эти теги просто текстом придут

Comment: Значит `'\n'` для переноса используйте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `"\n"`. `'Имя: ' + form.cleaned_data['name'] + '\n'`